# Failure in CICD Pipeline when trying to push on GitLab

Tags: python, gitlab, cicd

I am working on a project that I recently pushed to Git Lab. I am unable to discern what error it is as I am rather new with CI/CD pipeline, and I am hoping someone would be able to help me with this. The error is shown below:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f75d3d12e90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))': /simple/aiobotocore/
```

Appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: `'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.'` is a rather clear error message.

Comment: Does this mean it has something to do with my connection? I am currently using a work laptop connected to a VPN. Could that be a reason why? @KlausD.